# One static and one normal class share the same configuration?

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a configuration class that is shared in my project:

```
public class BarcodeConfig
{
    public string LotStandardDigits { get; set; }
    public string LotOldStandardDigits { get; set; }
    public int LotOldNumofDigits { get; set; }
    public int LotStandardNumofDigits { get; set; }
}
```

In my main class implementation i have 2 classes. One static (for utilities and the other that contains all my intended logic:

```
public static class BarcodeUtil
{
...
}

public class BarcodeBLL
{
...        
}
```

I want to be able to use the same configuration class for both my static and normal class. Is it best to make the config class static? or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer instantiating config object. In case of those static methods I'd pass the config as an argument to each of this utlility methods separately.

This allows to use utility methods for completely different purposes by completely different modules at the same time and makes them more elastic.

Comment: Ok using OOP operations on my config class seems right. Passing the config each time to my util methods feels also right becasue i make target different domain each time. For my normal class should i just pass the object in the constructor then?

Comment: Agree. But don't pass entire config object, only values which are needed for helper method you want to call.

Comment: Agree. Static utility class means stateless.

Comment: @ValtasarIII: And how to do that? you mean to just pass the fields separately?

Comment: @e4rthdog Yes, for normal class passing in constructor is ok for me. Doing this You bind your instance with a config instance which is the idea i like.

Comment: @e4rthdog Yes, pass them separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you use unit tests it's better not to have static classes, because it's much harder to fake them. This is an interesting discussing:

[When to use static vs instantiated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185605/when-to-use-static-vs-instantiated-classes)

Comment: @e4rthdog: Edited my answer, see the link.