# OOP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, oop

I have following class.

```
    class User 
    {
        private $userRoles = array();

        //Populate the user object when it's created
        public function __construct($dbConn,$user_id)
        {

                self::loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id);//Initiate the userroles
        }

        //Fill the array with this user's roles, it's
        protected static function loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id)
        {
            $fetchRoles = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT tbl_user_role.role_id, tbl_roles.role_name FROM tbl_user_role JOIN tbl_roles ON tbl_user_role.role_id = tbl_roles.id WHERE tbl_user_role.user_id = :user_id");
            $fetchRoles->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
            $fetchRoles->execute();
                    //Populate the array
            while($row = $fetchRoles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

                $this->userRoles[$row["role_name"]] = Role::getRole($dbConn,$row["role_id"]); 
(Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context.)
            }
        } 
    }
```

Getting above error on this `function protected static function loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id)`. I am working with role based access control.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $this but you are outside object.
protected **static** function loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id)
the static function doesn execute in the object so you have 2 opportunities:
1) return the roles and do whatever  you want later:

```
$roles = array();
while($row = $fetchRoles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $roles[$row["role_name"]] = Role::getRole($dbConn,$row["role_id"]); 
}
```

2) remove static keyword:

```
class User {
private $userRoles = array();

//Populate the user object when it's created
public function __construct($dbConn,$user_id)
{

    $this->loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id);//Initiate the userroles
}

//Fill the array with this user's roles, it's
protected function loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id)
{
    $fetchRoles = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT tbl_user_role.role_id, tbl_roles.role_name FROM tbl_user_role JOIN tbl_roles ON tbl_user_role.role_id = tbl_roles.id WHERE tbl_user_role.user_id = :user_id");
    $fetchRoles->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $fetchRoles->execute();
            //Populate the array
    while($row = $fetchRoles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $this->userRoles[$row["role_name"]] = Role::getRole($dbConn,$row["role_id"]); 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Static objects and functions do not have access to `$this`. If you're creating this with `$user = new User()`, then you need to change the call in your `__construct()` method:

```
public function __construct($dbConn,$user_id)
{
    $this->loadRoles($dbConn,$user_id);//Initiate the userroles
}
```

More information on static vs instantiated classes can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185605/when-to-use-static-vs-instantiated-classes).

**Edit** As simon reminded me, the function itself would need to have the `static` keyword removed as well.

Comment: This will still fail because `loadRoles()` is still `static` or am I missing something?

Comment: It should still work. When a class is instantiated, you can call static functions non-statically, and it works fine. You just can't go the other way. You can remove the static keyword though, to remove confusion.

Comment: Yes I know, what I meant is that OP is using `$this` inside `loadRoles()` and that won't work as long as `loadRoles()` is static.

Comment: Hmm. You may be right. I was thinking you could call static functions non-statically when it was instantiated. It may still work, but a warning would be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, but the only thing is that you have to remove static from the function, then only it will work.